# What geometrical notation marks acute and obtuse angles?

Tags: geometry

The geometrical notation for marking a right angle is a square box $\square$.

The notation for marking a measured angle is to make an arc $\measuredangle$, and the arc can be marked with one or more ticks to denote congruence.

Is there a geometrical notation for marking an angle as acute? Or obtuse?

Comment: Answer : no, up to my knowledge...

Comment: Thank you @JeanMarie. As a follow-up if you happen to have a suggestion for what would be good notation I would be interested to hear it.

Comment: A suggestion : a simple arc before 90° and a double arc beyond 90°...